# Facing Problem in PostgresSQL query for JSON data

Tags: json, postgresql

I am having following data

```
{
    "City": "Fontana", 
    "Timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
    "Longitude": "-117.4864123",
    "Timestamp": "2020-07-15T12:13:00-07:00",
    "refs": ["123", "456", "789"], "tZone": "PPP"
}
```

above data store against analytis.col_json column

I am having table structure

```
CREATE TABLE analytics 
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    col_typ character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    col_json json,
    cre_dte timestamp without time zone,    
    CONSTRAINT clbk_logs_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

[image]

The above records are in n-rows.

I am trying to fetch records on basis of 'refs' by sending list of string. for example:-
I have a separate List as a right side values to be filter on my table.

My query is as following

```
select * FROM public.analytics 
where col_json-> 'refs' in (
'123',
'pqa',
'bhu',
'qwerty'
);
```

but above query is not working for me.

Comment: Should `refs` contain **all** of the strings in your list, or only at least one?

Answer (score 1):

The more advanced JSON capabilities are only available when using the `jsonb`  type, so you will have to cast your column every time you want to do something non-trivial. It would be better to define the column as `jsonb` in the long run.

---

You can use the `?|` operator

```
select a.*
from analytics a
where col_json::jsonb -> 'refs' ?| array['123','pqa','bhu','qwerty'];
```

Note that this only works if all array elements are strings. It does not work with numbers e.g. if the json contained `"refs": [123,456]` it will **not** work.

Alternatively you can use an EXISTS condition with a sub-query:

```
select a.*
from analytics a
where exists (select * 
              from json_array_elements_text(a.col_json -> 'refs') as x(item) 
              where x.item in ('123','pqa','bhu','qwerty'));
```

---

If you want `refs` to contain **all** of the values in your list you can use the contains operator `@>`

```
select a.*
from analytics a
where a.col_json::jsonb -> 'refs' @> '["123", "456"]';
```

Or alternatively: `where a.col_json @> '{"refs": ["123", "456"]}'`

The above will only return rows where both values are contained in the `refs` array.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=685e52584c93113a9ddbf4fff6121376)

Comment: It gives an error

org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.sql.DBSQLException: SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function jsonb_array_elements(json) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 94

Comment: As I wrote in my last sentence: if your column isn't defined as `jsonb` you need to cast it.

Comment: Problem with second query is I have a list which should be parameterized to JPA method. and might be difficult to add list into second query. although first query is seems like some grammatical problems.

Comment: Yes, definitely my column is of json type

Comment: I changed the queries to include the cast. But you should really consider changing that column to `jsonb` in the long run

Comment: Yup, got your comments, and thank you for providing online example, which is most useful. may be I was using different PG Editor which is showing function not exist error. Thank you for your help. it is working for me. Have a good day :)

Comment: can you please help me in understanding performance wise `jsonb` is better than `json` column type ?

Comment: There is no (noticeable) performance difference. But `jsonb` storage is more efficient. [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) "*In general, most applications should prefer to store JSON data as jsonb*"

Comment: does `json` to `jsonb` casting involving more cost ? coz I have 1 millions of records in table. I dont think DB updations possible in future.